# GLSL: ShaderMaterial with custom shader is not transparent

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl

I try to draw a texture onto a sphere like this:

```
script(type='x-shader/x-vertex')#Vertex
  varying vec2 vUv;
  void main() {
  vUv = uv;
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
  }      

script(type='x-shader/x-fragment')#Fragment
  uniform sampler2D baseTexture;
  varying vec2 vUv;

  void main() {                   
    vec4 baseColor = texture2D( baseTexture, vUv );  
    gl_FragColor = baseColor;
  }

this.materials = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( { 
  uniforms: this.uniforms, 
  vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'Vertex' ).textContent, 
  fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'Fragment' ).textContent,
  transparent: true,
  blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending 
});
```

This does work fine, but the texture is not transparent, even if I change the alpha value. Transparent pixels from my texture are just black.

But if I write baseColor.a = 0.0, I cannot see the texture anymore, but also not what lies behind it in the scene. I think I'm missing mixing the texture with the background somehow?

How can I achieve this with GLSL in three.js?

Thanks

Comment: Have you enabled blending and set it to use alpha blending mode?This line :blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending  - why is it additive? It won't do alpha blending.

Comment: Part of the reason your transparent texels are black probably has to do with the order you are drawing. You are writing to the depth buffer which prevents anything behind the surface from being drawn even though the texel is supposed to be transparent. One solution is to enable alpha testing (in modern OpenGL this was removed and you have to do it in the fragment shader -- something like `if (gl_FragColor.a < 0.0001) discard;`), but the better solution is to draw everything that is opaque first, and then sort your translucent geometry from back-to-front.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how THREE.js works under hood but I see you set blending to be additive.That's not what you want for alpha blending.[Alpha blending](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transparency.htm) uses 
this function :

```
 glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

while additive uses:

```
  glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE);
```

So make sure you use the first one and that your texture has in fact alpha channel as A component of RGBA.